# What are some upper bounds on sums of the form $\sum_{n = c}^{\infty} n^{-a}e^{-bn}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

Are there any good bounds on sums of the form
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = c}^{\infty} n^{-a}e^{-bn}
\end{align*}
where $a, b > 0$, $c \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: i think this canbe bounded by a Gammafunction if one employs Euler MacLaurin#

Comment: Since the summand is decreasing, we can bound this quantity in terms of the upper complete Gamma function, which is usually defined as an integral of a function related to the summand here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function You might find http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00025-012-0263-9 useful.

Answer (score 0):

$$
c^{-a}\,e^{-bc}<\sum_{n = c}^{\infty} n^{-a}e^{-bn}<c^{-a}\sum_{n = c}^{\infty}e^{-bn}=c^{-a}\,\frac{e^{-bc}}{1-e^{-b}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! That's a very simple but nice bound. Though I might wonder if something tighter is possible

Comment: The lower and upper bound are of the same order. The only thing you can improve is the constant $1/(1-e^{-b})$.